# Image downloaded from Azure Storage not being displayed

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin. I'm trying display a list of downloaded images. I am downloading images from an APP API on Azure, where I stored the file on Azure Storage.

My server code is the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string PK, string RK)
{
    //Creating CloudBlockBlolb...

    byte[] bytes = new byte[blockBlob.Properties.Length]

    for(int i = 0; i < blockBlob.Properties.Length; i++){
        bytes[i] = 0x20;
    }

    blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(bytes, 0);

    HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
    return resp;
}
```

My Xamarin code is the following:

```
public MainPage ()
{
    //...

    List<PicturePost> list = new List<PicturePost>{
         new PicturePost("title", "subtitle", "link/api/Pictures?PK=xxx&RK=yyy")
    };

    InitializeComponent ();
    listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(CustomImageCell));
    listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
    listView.ItemsSource = list;

    //...
}
```

And here is the relevant code for CustomImageCell:

```
var image = new Image ();
image.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, "image");
//...
horizontalLayout.Children.Add (image);
```

I know that my API call works, because when I test it on the browser, it returns the image. I also know that if I use any random links such as http://www.natureasia.com/common/img/splash/thailand.jpg the image is downloaded and displayed properly. It is only when I use the API link that it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the container or blob set to public? can you debug and see if you are getting 403 (forbidden)? if that's the case either work on passing storage key for authentication or change the container/blob to public in order to access it from anywhere

Comment: @BrunoFaria It was private. I set it to public, and it did not change anything.  However, now that i think about it. When I go thru the API call, I am still able to access the image. I'm guessing because I am passing thru the API, I don't need to set the container to public.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. You don't need if you are passing access token with your request.

Answer (score 0):

so in my public MainPage(), I added the following:

```
listView.BeginRefresh ();
listView.EndRefresh ();
```

I realized at some point that the images would take some time to download. I assume that when the listView was created, the images were not finished downloading, so I added the code above... Pretty sure this is not the best way to do this (probably an await would be better, but I don't know where).